# I found this frame at a garage sale, and wanted to know if it was a GT frame if so what kind? The serial number I found on the bottom is GB06070827?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

[image][image][image]
Bike frame I'm wanting to build if it would be worth my time.

Comment: These questions are very hard to answer.  The serial number is only useful if you already know the maker, AND that maker kept records or a decodable schema.    Your best option is to ask the seller what it is, and if they have any photos of the bike before it was painted.

Comment: As for the "is it worth doing" part - you will have to buy or obtain every part that isn't the frame.  New, that will likely cost more than buying a brand new bike.  So you're digging into the used parts bins and ebay etc.  With patience, its possible to find enough parts to assemble your bike eventually.

Comment: If you want to ride an orange BMX and its about your size, then go for it.  Otherwise its just some scrap metal that has been overpainted.

Comment: Finally  +1 for a well-described question and including photos.

Comment: There's nothing at all unique about that frame -- I've seen dozens like it.  The only oddity is that the BB *appears* to be threadless.

Answer (score 2):

It's virtually certainly some kind of department store BMX. The welded-on pants-guard attachment points, the battleaxe-like dropouts (which did have their era on actual BMX bikes, but most of that time also overlapped with the ubiquity of 14mm axles), kickstand plate, and the threaded 1" steerer combine to point pretty decidedly in that direction.